# IP forwarding through ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, iptables, nat, forwarding, lte

The situation involves 3 machines:

- **A** Some laptop connected somewhere to the Internet via any mean
- **B** A server connected to the Internet through a standard ISP (static IP provided by dyndns: myserver.dyndns.com)
- **C** Another server connected
  to the internet via a 4G Dongle

**A** <--- ISP1 --- ISP 2 ---> **B** <--- ISP 2 --- 4G ---> **C**

As the 4G dongle rejects new incoming connections, I put in place an `autossh` channel to connect from A to C via B:

```
autossh -M 0 -N user@myserver.dyndns.com -R 10022:127.0.0.1:22 -R 10000:127.0.0.1:10000
```

That works great.

Now, I would like to access the 4G dongle's web interface by typing

```
myserver.dyndns.com:80
```

So I tried NATing things:

- On **B**:

  ```
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:10000
  ```

  and

  ```
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 10000 -j MASQUERADE`
  ```
- On **C**:

  ```
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 10000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.8.1:80
  ```

  and

  ```
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
  ```

Note: `eth1` is the 4G dongle's interface, **C**'s IP on that interface is 192.168.8.100 and the dongle's is 192.168.8.1.

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I also activated IP forwarding:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

When typing

```
iptables -t nat -L -v -n
```

on **B** and **C**, only the PREROUTING line of **B** sees its packet count increase after each attempt.

This may be due to a non-complete understanding of how `netfilter` works .

I'd appreciate any help you could provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, could you provide `iptables -t filter -nvL` outputs on servers B and C?

I guess the `autossh` channel runs on server C. Is it right? If so, I suggest a different approach. On B, you need a REDIRECT rule, because the kernel will not allow an unprivileged user to open the port 80.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 10000
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
```

**(EDIT)**: On server B, `GatewayPorts` must be enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
GatewayPorts clientspecified
```

On server C, forward connections directly to the dongle by modifying `autossh` arguments:

```
autossh -M 0 -N user@myserver.dyndns.com -R 10022:127.0.0.1:22 \
    -R :10000:192.168.8.1:80
```

---

The only error I see in your setup resides on the `PREROUTING` chain rule of server C. In this scenario, it will not be evaluated because it affects only packets that enters through network interfaces. Connections created by `ssh` are locally generated, so they would be affected by rules in `OUTPUT` chain.

Comment: Hi @Anderson. Thanks a lot for your help: the REDIRECT target and the GatewayPorts setting were the two keywords. The first can put into perspective with other posts such as [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/363899/iptables-dnat-from-loopback): DNAT seems to be forbidden for localhost destination. For the record, I tried to DNAT to a non loopback ip assigned to B (e.g. its eth0 ip) and it worked too!

Comment: @Thomas, There is a third keyword. The first colon in `-R :10000:192.168.8.1:80` argument makes SSH to bind the remote socket to the wildcard address (if `GatewayPorts` allows it). SSH binds listening sockets to the loopback addresses (`127.0.0.1` and `::1`) by default and neither `REDIRECT` nor `DNAT` target would work in this case.